# Гибкость русского языка

Tags: словообразование

Любой язык, в том числе и русский - имеет свои правила!
Но, насколько эти правила приемлемы к творчеству?
Во многих стихах можно увидеть искажённую форму слова...

По утверждению автора, в авторском тексте - автор вправе делать с ним всё, что захочет!

В словах появляется неправильное ударение - в угоду рифме.

Последний раз была дискуссия по слову - непогода, но во мн. числе - **непогод**

Одни говорят, что нет такого - **непогод**!

Другие ссылаются на Пушкина!!! - там оно есть...

Что скажете по этому поводу?

Comment: По правилам русского языка: "эти правила применимы к творчеству", "приемлемы к" - вообще не по-русски. По утверждению какого автора? Уточните вопрос.

Comment: По утверждению автора стихотворного текста, который он написал.
Автор в данном случае не известен широкой публике - скажем так - начинающий автор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если автор владеет языком, он использует его как инструмент. В этом случае ошибки – вовсе не ошибки, а художественный прием (речевая характеристика персонажа, шутка, неологизм). Если же малограмотный автор допускает ошибки, воображая, что говорит правильно, грамотный читатель не может не заметить беспомощность такого автора, а беспомощность автора – это то, что выбрасывает произведение за пределы искусства.

Comment: Спасибо за содержательный ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Любой может писать так, как он хочет. Другое дело, как это воспринимают те, кто его читает. Если "искажение" подчинено высшей цели или удачно само по себе, то ради Бога. Если же оно является следствием невежества, неуважения к языку или просто жалкой попыткой прикрыть свою бездарность, то отношение будет соответствующее.

Comment: В общем, если на слух воспринимается хорошо, но является отступлением от правил, то это вполне допустимо, и не является грубой ошибкой - речь идёт о творчестве!

Comment: Это смотря какой слух.